# Listener Binding; Cannot Find the Setter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to implement [listener bindings](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#listener_bindings), but when I run my code I get the following error:

```
Caused by: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type lambda on android.widget.Button. file:~/GithubBrowser/app/src/main/res/layout/loading_state.xml loc:30:31 - 30:52 ****\ data binding error ****
```

This is the layout file in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <import type="com.example.app.data.model.Resource"/>
        <import type="com.example.app.data.model.Status"/>
        <variable name="resource" type="Resource"/>
        <variable name="callback" type="com.example.app.ui.common.RetryCallback"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_margin">

        <Button android:id="@+id/retry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/retry"
            android:onClick="@{() -> callback.retry()}"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

And this is the `RetryCallback` interface referenced in the layout:

```
package com.example.app.ui.common

interface RetryCallback {

    fun retry()

}
```

---

#### Edit

The top-level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.android_tools_version = '3.0.0-alpha3'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-5'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_tools_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

ext {
    architecture_version = '1.0.0-alpha2'
    constraint_version = '1.0.2'
    dagger_version = '2.11'
    espresso_version = '2.2.2'
    glide_version = '3.7.0'
    junit_version = '4.12'
    mockito_version = '2.7.19'
    mock_server_version = '3.6.0'
    moshi_version = '1.5.0'
    retrofit_version = '2.2.0'
    support_version = '25.4.0'
    timber_version = '4.5.1'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the app module `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled !project.hasProperty('android.injected.invoked.from.ide')
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraint_version"

    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$architecture_version"
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$architecture_version"
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$architecture_version"

    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"

    compile "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshi_version"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit_version"

    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"

    compile "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timber_version"

    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_tools_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$architecture_version"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$architecture_version"

    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"
    testCompile "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:$mock_server_version"
    testCompile ("android.arch.core:core-testing:$architecture_version", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-ccore-utils'
    })

    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"

    androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
    })

    androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espresso_version", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
    })

    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockito_version"
}
```

Comment: weird. it works like a charm for me... do you have any other issues? could you post your `build.gradle`s?

Comment: @Lovis Sure, added

Comment: remove `kapt { generateStubs = true }`, it's not allowed with kapt3 (and you're using kapt3, since you `apply plugin kotlin-kapt`
if that doesn't help it's probably a Studio 3.0 issue, and I would wait until it's final

Comment: @Lovis Ah, I didn't even think to check if it was a 3.0 issue. I had tried with and without `kapt { generateStubs = true }` though. I opened the project in 2.3.3 (and lowered the gradle version), and it ran fine! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you try adding `dataBinding { addDefaultAdapters true }`? It seems like the default adapters are not available. And if this doesn't work, it would be interesting to see the databinding dependencies available with `./gradlew :app:dependencies`

Comment: Accept Matej Drobnic's answer!

Comment: maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555455/2472350) will, I fixed mine.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I just had that issue and I have managed to solve it by deleting .idea, .gradle and <strike>gradle</strike> folders and let Android Studio recreate whole project from scratch from gradle files.

2022 UPDATE: Do not delete gradle folder, only .gradle and .idea.

Comment: Thank you. It works. What I know now is, if something error happens, first delete .gradle file and  then .idea file :D

Comment: @AjayShrestha deleting the .gradle fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: deleting .gradle and .idea worked for me, I was getting issue on getter method. Good catch, thanks for the same!

Comment: It's working. in my case, I had changed project package Name and App Name. 
I think the Android studio has confused.

Comment: THIS!!! I lost about 2 hours to this, going through stackoverflow with a magnifying glass. Kept finding things saying "it's an error with your xml, make sure your variables are right, public getters etc. etc."... - nothing was wrong, just an ugly as hell android studio bug. This should be accepted answer.

Comment: @Matej Drobnic Thanks, I have been struggling with this issue for past 3 days and got a solution on this thread. Any idea why this problem occurs?

Comment: No idea. It looks like something breaks within Android Studio.

Comment: @AjayShrestha has it right. Delete .gradle and .idea files, BUT NOT gradle folder. I just deleted the third one, and it trashed my project. Now I have to pull everything back in from Git.

Answer (score 46):

Make sure `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` is in build.gradle.

If you are running in to this and no amount of rebuilding the project, deleting directories, clearing AS settings do anything. The IDE is fine without having it but the building fails.

It would be nice if android studio had better error messages for this.

Comment: This one is helpful. Cleaning project and deleting .idea & .gradle files didn't help, but applying plugin did.

Comment: Indeed. Cleaning & re-importing didn't help. Looks like the android plugin has a "silent" dependency on "kapt" plugin. If it's not satisfied and you have databinding annotations in your module it'll give the above error message.
I'm astonished the @androiddev guys didn't added a helpful message so far!

Answer (score 2):

The error `Cannot find the setter for attribute` means, it cannot find setter method that accepts the variable of the data type you provided as a parameter for that attribute.

That means it won't find the BindingAdapter method that you have defined. I had this issue because I was providing a wrong data type in XML layout to a custom attribute that I defined using BindingAdapter. Once I gave the correct data type to the custom attribute, it worked.

So, check if you are providing correct data type to the custom attributes that you may have defined using BindingAdapters.

Answer (score 1):

Just rebuild the project. It is probably because you did some refactoring

Answer (score 1):

Valid case:
This error is raised if you have an error in the xml file. First read carefully through the xml and if you find a problem fix it.

Invalid case:
For me the issue was raised for a file that was already deleted from the project or the file was renamed and the databinding was referencing the old file.

I'm not sure how to get rid of the issue every time but I have a number of things that sometimes work and sometimes don't.

Fix number 1:

Running 'gradle wrapper' in the project root.

Fix number 2:

Android Studio Clean Project

Next delete these folders in the project root:

rm -rf .gradle/

rm -rf app/build/

rm -rf build

rm -rf gradle

rm -rf gradlew

Android Studio Invalidate and restart

Everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: can I ask how to run gradle wrapper in the project root? I face this issue almost every time I compile the app

Comment: @leyreyyan If you are are on a mac you can run 'brew install gradle'. Also I have added an additional fix that sometimes works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`Rebuilding` project worked for me.

- Rebuild project from **`Build>Rebuild`**
- Fix issues if you get in build logs.
- Rebuild project again from **`Build>Rebuild`**

Answer (score 1):

If a similar kind of problem is encountered for a member variable of type `LiveData` then check your lambda in the XML file as for calling a function in `onClick` of a view `"@{() -> variableName.callMethod()}"` is used whereas for a variable `"@{variableName.memeberVariableName}"` is used.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete .gradle folder.
2. Run the project.
3. Clean the project.
4. Run the project.

Work for me.
If the order mix or miss , its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by all other fellow brothers, yes the error resolves after deleting .idea, .gradle and gradle folders.

(this is just for someone curious why this happens, below is my usecase):
i think this problem caused in my project because of i added one rxRecycleViewDataBinding custom library lately which might caused some binding errors by mixing binding references.