# msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String in data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding, two-way-binding

I am trying to use data binding in the edittext, In the morning it is working fine but suddenly got the error:

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String on android.widget.EditText. file:/home/itstym/ApkProjects/Reminder/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml loc:20:4 - 34:40 ****\ data binding error ****
```

EditText at line 20:4 -34:40

```
 <EditText
        app:error="@{login.errorEmail}"
        android:text="@={login.userEmailAddress}"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:id="@+id/email_address"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>
```

View Holder:

```
 @Bindable
var userEmailAddress:String = String()
    set(userEmailAddress){
        field=userEmailAddress
        notifyPropertyChanged(R.id.email_address)
        /*to check Email for validation on every character inserted by user*/
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.errorEmail)
    }
    get() {
    return field
}
```

What went suddenly wrong?

Solution tried:
1. Invalidate cache and restart.
2. Clean project and Rebuild project.

Comment: did you try, just for testing, using one-way-binding?

Comment: Actually it was working in the morning, but Now it not. Yup I tried one way binding also but end up getting the same error @pskink

Comment: then if it was working remove 'build' folder completly and try again

Comment: same error @pskink

Comment: then use "local history" option from android studio and restore your project to the state from the morning when everything worked fine

Comment: @pskink i have load the old code but It is also not working. same error

Comment: `"Actually it was working in the morning, but Now it not"` so was it working or not?

Comment: It was. @pskink but not now.

Comment: @pskink I think near get() there is some syntax error. may be

Comment: so remove the getters / setters for now and try to locate the source of your error

Comment: What a heck. I just removed the android:text line then build the app. Then agian add the android:text line build it again. Everything is working as usual. @pskink

Comment: The same happened on my side with a full java project.I finally reboot my mac, rm android build directories and start Android Studio 2.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Remove get() method from userEmailAddress as Kotlin provide Synthetic property access in it, you can direct access userEmailAddress without get()

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to bring [the answer from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44989266/355456) here (courtesy of Matej Drobnič) :

> "I just had that issue and I have managed to solve it by deleting .idea, .gradle
>   and gradle folders and let Android Studio recreate whole project from
>   scratch from gradle files."

I have run into this problem many times. It always involves some cleaning, deleting, restarting.  For me, this answer is probably the most reliable way to remedy this flaw of Android Studio.