# Data binding: Cannot bind ArrayAdpater to AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView in my layout.xml file like so

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/warehouseDropdown"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/warehouse"
    android:adapter="@{viewModel.warehouseAdapter}/>
```

The problem is when I try to build the project, I get the following error:

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:adapter' with parameter type android.widget.ArrayAdapter on android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView. file:.../app/src/main/res/layout/activity_scan.xml loc:52:43 - 52:68 ****\ data binding error ****
```

But, if I remove the `android:adapter` line from the layout.xml file, and setup the binding from the activity directly, it works just fine. Like so,

```
AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView warehouseDropdown = findViewById(R.id.warehouseDropdown);
warehouseDropdown.setAdapter(viewModel.getWarehouseAdapter());
```

I have already tried clearing the IDE generated files as said here: 
[Listener Binding; Cannot Find the Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594475/listener-binding-cannot-find-the-setter). Even this does not seem to solve my problem.

Comment: how does your binding definition looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:adapter' with
>   parameter type android.widget.ArrayAdapter on
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView

As it says, I looked [`AutoCompleteTextViewBindingAdapter`](http://%20https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/android-6.0.0_r7/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/AutoCompleteTextViewBindingAdapter.java). and could not find any BindingAdapter related to `android:adapter` namespace. They have not yet defined it.

You can create your [Binding Adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) if you want.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:adapter")
public static void setAutoCompleteAdapter(AutoCompleteTextView textView, ArrayAdapter adapter) {
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Now I am wondering how the `@BindingAdapter` works (in any random package in any random class) without adding any additional configuration.

Comment: Data binding generate java classes, for that you have written in xml. You can check uses of `setAutoCompleteAdapter` to check that autogenerated class. and yes you can place `BindingAdapter` anywhere in your code.