# e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, viewmodel

I have enabled databinding, but while I execute the code I get this error.

### error

e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.

I created a fragment class and XML for that class.
Im able to import datbindingutil class.

I have done rebuilt/ sync with gradle files/ invalidate cache and restart, nothing worked.

### xml

```
<layout>

<!--suppress AndroidUnknownAttribute -->
<data class=".databinding.ProfileFragmentBinding">

    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.sample.sample.user.User" />

    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="com.sample.sample.user.UserViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="handler"
        type="com.sample.sample.user.profile.ProfileFragment" />
</data>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileIV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:url="@{user.avatarUrl}" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profileIV"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profileIV">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profileNameLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/myriad_pro_semibold"
            android:text="@{user.name}"
            android:textColor="@color/black_transparent_de"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_regular"
            tools:text="NAME" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/badgeLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/myriad_pro_semibold"
            android:text="@{user.badge}"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_regular"
            tools:text="Superman" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_Label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="@{user.badge}"
            android:textColor="@color/green_39b54a"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
            tools:text="farmer_v1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/badgeIV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:error="@{@drawable/ic_profile_default_grey_24dp}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:placeholder="@{@drawable/ic_profile_default_grey_24dp}"
        app:url="@{user.badgeUrl}" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/locationPinIV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_pin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profileIV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileIV" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileAddressTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/narrow"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/locationPinIV"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/locationPinIV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/locationPinIV"
        tools:text="bangalore, Karnataka" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dobIV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dob"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/profileAddressTV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileIV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/narrow"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/locationPinIV"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/dobIV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/locationPinIV"
        tools:text="born on 01/01/2000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activityLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/big"
        android:fontFamily="@font/myriad_pro_semibold"
        android:text="@string/activities"
        android:textColor="@color/black_transparent_de"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_regular"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profileIV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locationPinIV" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dividerV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/regular"
        android:background="@color/grey_000000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activityLabel" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dividerV">

        <!--<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:pager="@{(pager)}"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextTab"
            app:tabTextColor="#b4ffffff" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout"
            app:handler="@{handler}"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />-->

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### class

```
    class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var mFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private lateinit var mBinding: ProfileFragmentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        return mBinding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        val vm: UserViewModel = getViewModel(mFactory)
        mBinding.vm = vm
        //mBinding.handler = this
        //mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
    }

    /*@BindingAdapter("bind:handler")
    fun bindViewPagerAdapter(view: ViewPager, activity: MainActivity) {
        val adapter = ProfilePagerAdapter(view.context, activity.supportFragmentManager)
        view.adapter = adapter
    }

    @BindingAdapter("bind:pager")
    fun bindViewPagerTabs(view: TabLayout, pagerView: ViewPager) {
        view.setupWithViewPager(pagerView, true)
    }*/
}
```

Comment: did you find fix for this issue?

Comment: from invalidate cache->select only invalidate, then close the project and remove project from the suggestion and restart android studio and open project again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63193286/4718406

Answer (score 19):

in my case I was able to find it when the mouse was hovering that line in the build output, as shown here:

without hover:
[image]

with hover:
[image]

it's really a shame how they show the error, for the simplest error ever, I was trying 10 different solutions as well invalidating the cache and ...

**UPDATE**:

you can also click here :

[image]

and you'll get something like this:

[image]

which is very detailed information about the error, I was missing this button in 7 years of Android Development :D

Comment: Thanks! Also it's possible to press on error line, copy it, paste to text editor and check full stacktrace there.

Answer (score 4):

Run `./gradlew build --stacktrace` to check the details, which will tell you where the issue happens, something like:

> e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
>   Could not find accessor xx
>   file:xxx/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_xxxx.xml Line:108

Sometimes if you changed the property name, especially when changed by `refactor` => `rename`, the property name won't be changed in xml automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly this error occurs when the name of the variable passed in the XML file through data binding is incorrect. Just hover over the mouse on the error and you would be able to identify the culprit variable there.

Answer (score 0):

if it happen when change jdk versions, delete all build folders in every module that you have on the project,
It's fixed my issue.

delete caches folder to

finder -> home -> click on "command +shift + ." to see hidden folders -> .gradle -> caches