# build exception in data binding antotaion processor malformed byte sequence

Tags: java, android, data-binding

logcat output

```
Cause: failure, see logs for details.
Exception while handling step  android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions@404e7fc5 javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
     - with linked exception:
    [org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.]
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:333)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:204)
        at android.databinding.tool.store.ResourceBundle$LayoutFileBundle.fromXML(ResourceBundle.java:763)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions$IntermediateV2.appendTo(ProcessExpressions.java:347)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:122)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:212)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:197)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:98)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.DelegatingProcessor.process(DelegatingProcessor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.NonIncrementalProcessor.process(NonIncrementalProcessor.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.DelegatingProcessor.process(DelegatingProcessor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.access$401(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor$5.create(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor$5.create(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:96)
        at **org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.track(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:117)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.process(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:96)
   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
        at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanLiteral(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
        ... 129 more
```

XML code the cause the exception

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/aliceblue">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_include"
                layout="@layout/title_back_toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fast_reports_box_width"
                android:layout_height="540dp"
                android:background="@drawable/curved_24dp_dark_gray_square"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_details"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_details"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_details" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_details"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fast_reports_header_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fast_reports_header_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fast_reports_header_margin_top"
                android:background="@drawable/curved_24dp_gray_square"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arabic_bold"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/details"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fast_reports_header_text_size"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_include" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_fast_detail_label"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fast_reports_label_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fast_reports_label_height"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_detail"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_details"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_details"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_details" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderNumField"
                style="@style/order_detail_field_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_first_field_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/order_number"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_details" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/order_detail_value_style"
                android:text="472642"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_orderNumField"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_orderNumField" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderCategoriesField"
                style="@style/order_detail_field_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_field_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/categories"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderNumField" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/order_detail_value_style"
                android:text="M5-MELSYA"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderCategoriesField"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_orderCategoriesField" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderPriceField"
                style="@style/order_detail_field_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_field_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/price"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderCategoriesField" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/order_detail_value_style"
                android:text="500 ريال"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_orderPriceField"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_orderPriceField" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderCustomerField"
                style="@style/order_detail_field_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_field_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/customer_name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderPriceField" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/order_detail_value_style"
                android:text="Abdalla Elnaggar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_orderCustomerField"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_orderCustomerField" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderPhoneField"
                style="@style/order_detail_field_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_field_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/phone_number"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderCustomerField" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/order_detail_value_style"
                android:text="0591000555"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_orderPhoneField"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_orderPhoneField" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderMobileField"
                style="@style/order_detail_field_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_field_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/mobile_number"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderPhoneField" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/order_detail_value_style"
                android:text="0591000555"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_orderMobileField"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_orderMobileField" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderPaymentField"
                style="@style/order_detail_field_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_field_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/payment_method"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderMobileField" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/order_detail_value_style"
                android:text="نقدا"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_orderPaymentField"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_orderPaymentField" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderِAddressField"
                style="@style/order_detail_field_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_field_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/address"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderPaymentField" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ordersAddress"
                style="@style/order_detail_value_style"
                android:text="الاسكندرية"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderِAddressField"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_orderِAddressField" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_location"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/order_item_margin_start"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_go_to_location"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderِAddressField" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arabic_regular"
                android:text="@string/location_on_map"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_location"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_location"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_location" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderِNoteField"
                style="@style/order_detail_field_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_field_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/order_notes"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_location" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderNote"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_field_margin_top"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arabic_regular"
                android:text="ت - ملاحظات - ملاحظات - ملاحظات - ملاحظات/n ملاحظات"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_orderِNoteField"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderِNoteField" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderStateField"
                style="@style/order_detail_field_style"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/order_detial_field_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/state"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderNote" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/order_detail_value_style"
                android:text="غير مكتمل"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_orderStateField"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_orderStateField" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/order_item_margin_start"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arabic_regular"
                android:text="13/13/2013"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_orderStateField" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/curved_24dp_blue_square"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arabic_bold"
                android:text="@string/proceed_selling"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_postpone"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/curved_24dp_gray_square"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arabic_bold"
                android:text="@string/postpone"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background" />


            <View
                android:id="@+id/comments_background"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/comment_section_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/background" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_comments"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="21dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_comment"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/comments_background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/comments_background" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arabic_bold"
                android:text="@string/comments"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ic_comments"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ic_comments"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ic_comments" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_refresh"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/comments_background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ic_comments" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arabic_bold"
                android:text="@string/refresh"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_refresh"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_refresh"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_refresh" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/comment_separator"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0.50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ic_comments" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rc_comments"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/comment_separator" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="134.0dp"
                android:layout_height="40.0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/curved_24dp_blue_square"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arabic_bold"
                android:text="اضافة تعليق"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rc_comments" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with that character below the A
rِAdd
this is not a utf8 character I dont know how it end up in my code I write Arabic and English on my app may I wrote Arabic character when I enter an id for a view

Answer (score 0):

in my case this error occurred after I changed my windows. I solved the problem after changed windows locale from setting -> language -> administration language settings -> change system locale

Comment: Which locale you used to solve the problem?