# Cannot call method ViewModel from xml with dataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I want to start increase the count by every second pass. When I want stop the counter by using method `stopCount()`, I can't call it by `OnClick` in xml.

I got this error:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
```

.

```
<data>
    <variable name="mainViewModel" type="com.ali.mvvm_livedata.MainViewModel"/>
    <variable name="count" type="String"/>
</data>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={mainViewModel.liveData}"
            android:onClick="@{() -> mainViewModel.stopCount()}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={mainViewModel.liveData}"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here my ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val timer = Timer()
private lateinit var timmer: TimerTask
val liveData: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

fun getTime(): MutableLiveData<String> {
    return liveData
}

fun count() {
    var tempCount = 0
    timmer = object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            tempCount++
            Log.i("currentCount", tempCount.toString())
        }
    }
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timmer, 1000, 1000)
}

internal fun stopCount() {
    timmer.cancel()
}
```

MainActivity code

```
 @Inject
lateinit var mModelFactory: ViewModelFactory

private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    binding.mainViewModel = mainViewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    mainViewModel.count()
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166846/e-kapt-an-exception-occurred-android-databinding-tool-util-loggederrorexcept

Comment: viewmodel method that will called using databinding (from xml) must be public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remove the internal(front of the fun stopCount)