# Databinding + Room in Kotlin. How to bind data class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-databinding

I have make one demo of Room database which is purely in kotlin and its successfully run. But now I convert that demo into databinding also.

Problem is that in kotlin we make data class as entity for room database. And in java we just make one pojo class. So its all about easy in Java but something different in kotlin.

My problem and my question is **How to i bind data class in kotlin?**

following is my data class

```
@Entity
data class Bill(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "billNo")
    var billNo: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "customerName")
    var customerName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "customerNo")
    var customerNo: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemList")
    @TypeConverters(ItemListConverter::class)
    var itemList: ArrayList<Item>
   ) {
       @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
      var billId: Int = 0
     }
```

Adapter Class

```
class BillAdapter(private val ctx: Context, private var payeeList: ArrayList<Bill>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BillAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

var listdata = payeeList
var layoutInflater:LayoutInflater? = null
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BillAdapter.ViewHolder {

    if(layoutInflater==null){
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    }

var binding:BillListItemBinding =  DataBindingUtil.inflate(this!!.layoutInflater!!, R.layout.bill_list_item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

//this method is binding the data on the list
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.bill =  listdata[position]

    }

//this method is giving the size of the list
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return listdata.size
}

   inner class ViewHolder(var binding: BillListItemBinding) : 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {}
}
```

Error at run time.

> e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding
>   errors.

app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'  // add this line

android {


    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.root.roomdatabinding"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.17'
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.1'

}
```

Comment: Add your build.gradle file else check kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2' you added this line in dependency

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan Not working.

Comment: add your build.gradle

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan see my edit

Comment: @TypeConverters(ItemListConverter::class) you added this line in AppDatabase class right? as you used in data class.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan yes.

Comment: Run ./gradlew build --stacktrace to check the details, which will tell you where the issue happens. Also try to invalidate and restart android studio

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594475/listener-binding-cannot-find-the-setter

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan. It was some problem in my layout. Thanks for helping. I understood that databinding works with data class in kotlin.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan  ./gradlew build --stacktrace command not work in my windows. Any about that ? Error is '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below code its useful for you:

```
class WeatherAdapter(val mContext: Context, private val guestLists:   List<WeatherData>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
private var weatherList: WeatherData? = null



override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.weather_row, viewGroup, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, i: Int) {
    weatherList = guestLists[i]



    viewHolder.bind(weatherList)

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return guestLists.size
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    private val mBinding: WeatherRowBinding?

    init {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView)
    }

    fun bind(weatherList: WeatherData?) {
        mBinding!!.setSetdata(weatherList)
    }
}
}
```